# How to change my button color permanent from pressing button on another activity button

Tags: java, android

This is my First Activity where i want to change button color by pressing button on another activity

```
    public void colorchangeOnfirstActivity(){
        Button btnA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.asmat_btn);     
btnA.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
    }
```

This is my second Activity where the second activity button is.

```
Button btnB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rose_btn);
  btnB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            asmat_activity secondActivity = new asmat_activity();
            asmat_activity.colorchangeOnfirstActivity();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Activities should never directly interact with each other. Generally, if you want to do something in response to an action in another Activity, you should use the Activity Result APIs.

So, for example, you may start your secondary Activity with a request code:

```
// The request code can be any integer value you wish
startActivityForResult(activityIntent, MY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Then in your new Activity, you can set a result to be delivered back to the Activity which started it. In your case, something like:

```
btnB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // This will deliver the result to the requesting Activity
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Then in your first Activity, you will override `onActivityResult` to handle the result:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == MY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        btnA.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: I will be so thankful to you if you solve it, i am on this project from last 1 week, please check this link so you understand it very well Sir. 
 https://docs.google.com/document/d/1La0fdTHtUauFKiVzm4bOHLbmajwFI_wyCaAgs8jC6XM/edit?usp=sharing